# Django - urls.py - Filenames with a hash/pound (#) sign?

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm using django and realized that when the filename that the user wants to access (let's say a photo) has the pound sign, the entry in the url.py does not match.

Any ideas?

```
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root':
    MEDIA_ROOT},
```

it just says:

```
"/home/user/project/static/upload/images/hello" does not exist
```

when actually the name of the file is:

```
hello#world.jpg
```

Thanks,
Nico

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't really Django's fault - the pound (#) sign in a URL means to load the specified anchor on the page. You need to encode the pound sign in your URL to get the browser to request the full image path:

```
/home/user/project/static/upload/images/hello%23world.jpg
```

In a Django template you can use the [urlencode](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#urlencode) template tag.

Comment: Just to add: the browser won't send anything to the server from the pound (#) sign onwards, this is why you need to encode it.